# Having issues with syntax in a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, syntax, cpython

I'm trying to write a python code with a while loop, where the user has to guess the correct number in order to exit the loop. I have seen answers for how to make the code run properly but every time I try to run my code I get a syntax error. I cannot tell what is wrong with the syntax, to me it looks correct? Please help.

this is my code:

```
secret_number = 777

guess_number = int(input("Enter your guess here: ")

while guess_number != secret_number:
    print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")
    guess_number = int(input("Enter your guess here: ")
    
print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")
```

This is the error:

```
 File "main.py", line 5

    while guess_number != secret_number:

        ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Add parentheses at the end of second and fifth lines.

Comment: Same error exists on the identical line in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the typo of a missing `)`, you *repeat* the error, presumably due to copy-and-pasting the line in question. Avoid this by using the following idiom for a loop that needs to run at least once.

```
while True:
    guess_number = int(input("Enter your guess here"))
    if guess_number == secret_number:
        break
    print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")

print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")
```

Now the input will be gathered at least once, but the loop can terminate before printing the error message and starting the next iteration.

Some languages have two different loop structures for checking the condition before and after the body executes. Python has only the pre-body form, so you need to simulate the post-body form using explicit flow-control like `break` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing brackets after

```py
int(input("..."))
```

To avoid mistakes like this try to use environments like `pycharm` or `visual studio`, they will make you notice mistakes like that

Comment: to format code inline you need to use ` at start and end (not ' but `), to format code blocks use ```language (where language is the programming language that you are formatting) at the start and ``` at the bottom (not ''' but ```), I will edit so you can take a look

Comment: also IDEs are pretty great but as suggested here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oij82Cp9K1A, newcomers should first try learning code without them or sth like that so that they better learn syntax and kinda learn better but then again that is only one's opinion (with quite valid points) and sure newcomers can use IDEs